# dlsym cannot find symbol that is listed by nm

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with the following simple example program, when I compile and run the program within a docker container based on ubuntu:bionic, running on my mac (I don't see why this would be relevant, but I wanted to emphasise I have no problem running this program on my mac natively).

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void myFunc() { }

int main() {
    auto handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL );
    dlerror();
    std::cout << "symbol addr = " << dlsym(handle,"myFunc") << std::endl;
    if (auto e = dlerror(); e) std::cout << " error = " << e << std::endl;
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
symbol addr = 0
 error = ./myExe: undefined symbol: myFunc
```

but if I do `nm ./myExe` I see: `0000000000000be0 T myFunc` listed plain as day

For comparison, compiling and running exactly the same thing on mac (clang compiler) I get:

```
symbol addr = 0x10ccdc090
```

and nm lists: `0000000100001080 T _myFunc` (I noticed on mac that underscore prefix seems to be a thing, but doesnt affect the dlsym finding the symbol)

Seriously, what am I missing here?? Thanks!

Comment: ok, managed to make it work by adding the `-export-dynamic` option to the call to the linker. But this leaves two outstanding questions for me: 1). Why does `nm` still list the symbol without this option? 2). Is there an alternative way to flag my specific function should be exported by the linker rather than using the linker option?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe MacOS will prepend an underscore automatically for `dlsym` call, quoting:

> In darwin objects, C symbols have an underscore prepended to the symbol name.  So, the function getpid() ends up in the object file as _getpid Most code assumes that there is no underscore and calls dlsym() with symbol as "getpid" which would fail to find the symbol.
>
> Depending on how the dlcompat package was built, the dlsym() function may, or may not, automatically prepend an underscore to the passed symbol to compensate for this.  In this case calling dlsym() with symbol as "getpid" does indeed find the _getpid symbol.

The documentation is from https://www.manpagez.com/man/3/dlopen/osx-10.3.php .